# Why doesn't expo-file-system work in Jest?

Tags: ios, react-native, testing, expo

I am trying to write some tests for my little project. We used expo-file-system to allow us access IOS internal storage. And here is my test for our saving function.

```
import SaveData from "../app/resources/SaveData/SaveData"
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

var promiseHolder = 0;

describe('\nsaveNewFile() is tested.\n', ()=>{
it("A file is going to be created.",async ()=>{
    await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync("sometext","test.txt");
    promiseHolder = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync("test.txt");
    testHolder = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync("test.txt");
    console.log(promiseHolder)
    console.log(testHolder)
  });
});
```

And here is the output.
[Command line output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccHBd.png)

It looks like FileSystem.documentDirectory does not work in test, but our app works well. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in `node_modules\jest-expo\src\preset\setup.js` you can find the `jest.mock("expo-file-system", () => ({...}));` call.

Notice that `documentDirectory` property is not included in the mock, which is why it is `undefined` when the tests are run.

I don't know how to get the current mock set for a module in jest (ie. as we often see with `...jest.requireActual(...)`), so if you want to give `documentDirectory` a value, the best solution I see is to copy\paste the entire `jest.mock(...)` call to your test file and add `documentDirectory` to the mocked module prior to running your tests.

ie.

```
jest.mock('expo-file-system', () => ({
    downloadAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ md5: 'md5', uri: 'uri' })),
    getInfoAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ exists: true, md5: 'md5', uri: 'uri' })),
    readAsStringAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    writeAsStringAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    deleteAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    moveAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    copyAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    makeDirectoryAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    readDirectoryAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    createDownloadResumable: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    documentDirectory: "file:///test-directory/",
  }));
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't declare testHolder variable like promiseHolder.

```
 import SaveData from "../app/resources/SaveData/SaveData";
 import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

 var promiseHolder = 0;
 var testHolder = 0;

describe('\nsaveNewFile() is tested.\n', ()=>{
it("A file is going to be created.",async ()=>{
   await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync("sometext","test.txt");
   promiseHolder = await 
   FileSystem.getInfoAsync("test.txt");
   testHolder = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync("test.txt");
   console.log(promiseHolder)
   console.log(testHolder)
    });
 });
```

Comment: Nah even though I change to this, console.log(testHolder) is still undefined. Also, I think the promiseHolder does not hold "sometext"... Is there someway I can know the value in the promiseHolder?

Comment: Can you update your last change in question with declaration of promiseHolder

Comment: I added another answer, can not edit current one, also your order of parameters in writeasyncstring was wrong. I think the file that exist in file system is not a file that you try to create. You can also have to think about askPermissions if you didn't

Answer (score -1):

You didn't declare gan variable like promiseHolder.

```
 import SaveData from "../app/resources/SaveData/SaveData";
 import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

 var promiseHolder = 0;
 var testHolder=0;

describe('\nsaveNewFile() is tested.\n', ()=>{
it("A file is going to be created.",async ()=>{
   let fileUri = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "text.txt";
   await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(flileUri, "cao");
   promiseHolder = await 
   FileSystem.getInfoAsync(fileUri);
   testHolder = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(fileUri);
   console.log(promiseHolder)
   console.log(testHolder)
    });
 });
```

Updates: 
expo-jest makes mockups for imports like FileSystem and results that were received in test intend to predefined mockup presets.

Comment: I changed the code to yours, matter's still there :(

Comment: I tried to log FileSystem.documentDirectory, it is undefined as well

Comment: Can you post the expo  snack ? Do work with expo-file-system  7.0.0 version and what expo version?

Comment: I got some errors when I run on snack... I work on expo 34.0.1, expo-file-system 6.0.2

Comment: Tried with 7.0.0

Comment: Updated that, same though

Comment: I can look remotely to your code in an hour through a anydesk

Comment: How can I send you the address?

Comment: can you provide anydesk?

Comment: its 599 133 667