# How do you mock FileSystem.cacheDirectory in jest?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, expo

I am trying to test a service that uses `expo-file-system`.  Specifically I just want to mock out `FileSystem.cacheDirectory` since that's the first instance of my code that uses `FileSystem`.

I tried `__mocks__/expo-file-system.ts`

```
export default {
  cacheDirectory: jest.fn(() => "<cache>/"),
};
```

And

```
jest.mock("expo-file-system", () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      cacheDirectory: jest.fn(() => "<cache>/"),
    };
  });
});
```

My test I think looks simple enough

```
import * as FileSystem from "expo-file-system";

// This part I tried commenting out 
jest.mock("expo-file-system", () => {
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      cacheDirectory: jest.fn(() => "<cache>/"),
    };
  });
});

it("verify mock", () => {
  expect(FileSystem.cacheDirectory).toBe("<cache>/");
});
```

But I always get `FileSystem.cacheDirectory` as `undefined`

I also have the `jest-expo` dependency and preset.

This is a simple scenario compared to [Why doesn't expo-file-system work in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262638/why-doesnt-expo-file-system-work-in-jest)

Answer (score 0):

If you look in `node_modules\jest-expo\src\preset\setup.js` you can find the `jest.mock("expo-file-system", () => ({...}));` call.

Notice that `cacheDirectory` property is not included in the mock, which is why it is `undefined` when the tests are run.

I don't know how to get the current mock set for a module in jest (ie. as we often see with `...jest.requireActual(...)`), so if you want to give `cacheDirectory` a value, the best solution I see is to copy\paste the entire `jest.mock(...)` call to your test file and add `cacheDirectory` to the mocked module prior to running your tests.

ie.

```
jest.mock('expo-file-system', () => ({
    downloadAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ md5: 'md5', uri: 'uri' })),
    getInfoAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ exists: true, md5: 'md5', uri: 'uri' })),
    readAsStringAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    writeAsStringAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    deleteAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    moveAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    copyAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    makeDirectoryAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    readDirectoryAsync: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    createDownloadResumable: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    cacheDirectory: "file:///test-directory/",
  }));
```